# Is there a way to keep Month Data from May 2019 to Jan 2020 in powerbi Bar chart

Tags: sorting, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

[image]I have an excel data with Data(from May 2019 to Jan 2020), few columns have been added in power bi mainly Month Number and Month Name.

For Month Name, sorting has been done by Month Number.

However, when i put the Bar graph, and sort it i get the bar graph from Jan 2020, May 2019, June 2019, July 2019 so on until Dec2019.(Image has been attached)

Do we have any way where we can put the graph starting from May 2019 all the way to Jan 2020 in x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a date field and using that in the chart instead. The calculation could be something like:

```
Month New = DATE([Year],[Month Number],1)
```

Then you can customize the date field to just show the MMM-YY part. This way your sorting issues will be resolved and you won't face any issues in the future as well.